# Login, create folder and upload file to Box account as service account

Tags: box-api

I reviewed the Box authentication documentation as well as the other StackOverflow questions but I'm still unable to find definite answer.

My client is an enterprise Box client and would like to build a company's internal web application that would login into Box.com using service/admin account and create folder and upload a file.  The uploaded folder will be available to specific customer that will login into Box and upload additional files.

I created a sequence diagram to depict the same.

[image]

Would you let me know if this is a supported Box authentication model?  Can the Box 2.0 Beta API Token be used to login as service account and create file/folder/share?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that could work for you.  Let me suggest the simplest one first, and if that is not sufficient, then I can suggest other ways to accomplish your goal.

You can use the regular Box authentication for your solution.  To do so, simply get an API key and an auth-token for your application.   Then, after you have uploaded your file, use the V2 API to create a [shared link](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file) for your file.   You can email that shared link to the client, and they can use the link to access the file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: Ramu, were you successful with this?

Answer (score 0):

there has been new developments since this question was posted, and now it's possible to use JWT (JSON Web Token) and Box Developers Edition to access Box.

If you create a developer account you will be able to create App users and login using an enterprise id and a private key file. Check out the docs for more information: [Box Developer Edition](https://developers.box.com/developer-edition/)

Additonally, [boxsdk](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk) comes with support for Box Developer Edition